# Should I use Custom helpers in Laravel instead of simple static methods of a class?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, composer-php, laravel-5.6, helper

**Helpers:**

We add arrayhelper.php to App\Helpers folder
Then we add

```
"files": [
      "app/helpers/arrayhelper.php",
]
```

to section

```
"autoload": {
}
```

in composer.json.

Now it's possible to define methods and use them globally.

**Static methods:**

make class ArrayHelper
define static method (e.g. `doSmthg()`)
and then it's possible to call it like this `ArrayHelper.doSmthg()`

**Question:**

**if there is some benefits (e.g. better performance, less memory usage) of using helpers in Laravel or it's just matter of habit?**

When to choose between helpers and static methods?

P.S. There was some similar questions, but I read through all answers and I didn't find what I exactly wanted to know.

Comment: In my own opinion it is always better to use functionality that already exists then creating my own. So I would say that it is better to create helpers for those few things that need a helper. But I also think that if you need a lot of them the laravel helper files get a bit crowded.

Comment: @Marcus that's true. If is slows the framework, probably not if not overused. It is only beneficial if certain functions are of common need. For instance, if it encompasses several tables or if it is table (model) independent. I use custom functions. Albeit very few. All helper functions are in-build Laravel functions. So yes. They are very common by design. Just don't overdo it.